# Generic classes an Inheritance

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes (classA and classB) that both inherits from same class (classC). Now I need create new generic class (classAA) that inherits List of A or B. Is it possible to call methods of classC in classAA.

```
public class classC
{
    //...
}
public class classA : classC
{
    //...
}
public class classB : classC
{
    //...
}
public class classAA<T> : List<T>
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you just want `where T : classC` as a constraint in your `classAA<T>` declaration? (As an aside, it's useful to follow naming conventions even in sample code...)

Comment: What does calling methods of `ClassC` mean for list of `ClassC`?

Comment: For example classC have method DrawObject(). And in classAA i want to call DrawObject() for each element in List.

Comment: Then you need to do what @JonSkeet said, you need to ensure that any object you pass to `classAA<T>` is at least of type `classC` (or a descendant) by using the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to inherit from `List<T>`. 95% of time you should prefer *composition* over *inheritance*. See for example: [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Most probably you are looking for something like:

```
public class classAA<T> 
    where T : ClassC
{
    public List<T> MyList { get; set; }

    public void Foo()
    {
        foreach (var item in this.MyList)
        {
            item.MethodOfClassC();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this. Assumming:

```
class classC
{
    public void DrawObject() { }
}
```

you can put constraint on `T` that it will be `classC` or its derivatives:

```
class classAA<T> : List<T> where T : classC
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        foreach (var item in this.Cast<classC>())
        {
            // here you can call item.DrawObject()
        }
    }
}
```